# python Can I duplicate a listbox in two notebook pages

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using python 3.4 and tkinter. I have a notebook with two pages. I have a listbox that needs to be on both pages.

I'm wondering if I can setup the listbox once and use it on both pages, or if I need to setup a separate listbox on each page and manage both as the list box in one page changes?

Comment: There is no reason you cant. There should be a few ways you can accomplish what you want. If you provide us with an example code of what you have tried so far someone should be able to assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pack/grid/place the listbox inside two different frames simultaneously.

However, you can re-pack/grid/place the listbox each time the notebook tab changes. To do so, I used the `<<NotebookTabChanged>>` event which is triggered each time the notebook tab changes:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
notebook.pack()

frame1 = tk.Frame(notebook, bg='red', width=400, height=400)
frame1.pack_propagate(False)

frame2 = tk.Frame(notebook, bg='blue', width=400, height=400)
frame2.pack_propagate(False)

notebook.add(frame1, text='frame 1')
notebook.add(frame2, text='frame 2')

var = tk.StringVar(root, 'a b c d e f g')
listbox = tk.Listbox(notebook, listvariable=var)

def display_listbox(event):
    tab = notebook.tabs()[notebook.index('current')]
    listbox.pack(in_=tab)

notebook.bind('<<NotebookTabChanged>>', display_listbox)

root.mainloop()
```

Explanations about `display_listbox`:

- `notebook.tabs()` returns `(frame1, frame2)` (i.e the tuple of the tabs)
- `notebook.index('current')` returns the index of the currently visible tab
- the `in_` option can be used to specify the widget in which we want to pack the listbox (it also works with `grid` and `place`)

Answer (score 0):

Sharing the same `listvariable` between the two list boxes is sufficient to keep them synchronized.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

rootWin = tk.Tk()
rootWin.title('Talk Like A Pirate')

listvar = tk.StringVar()

#create a notebook
pirateBook = ttk.Notebook(rootWin)

#create a tab
tab1 = tk.Frame(pirateBook)

#create a listbox in the tab
listbx1 = tk.Listbox(tab1,
    listvariable=listvar,
    height=21,
    width=56,
    selectmode='single'
    )
listbx1.pack()

#create another tab
tab2 = tk.Frame(pirateBook)

#create a listbox in the second tab
listbx2 = tk.Listbox(tab2,
    listvariable=listvar,
    height=21,
    width=56,
    selectmode='single'
    )
listbx2.pack()

#add the tabs to the notebook
pirateBook.add(tab1, text="Tab 1")
pirateBook.add(tab2, text="Tab 2")

#pack the notebook
pirateBook.pack()

#you can access the listbox through the listvariable, but that takes
#   a list as the argument so you'll need to build a list first:
ls=list()   #or you could just ls = []

#build a list for the list box
ls.append("Arr, matey!")
ls.append("Dead men tell no tales!")
ls.append("Heave ho, me hearties!")
ls.append("I'll cleave ye t'yer brisket a'fore sendin' ye to Davey Jones Locker!")

#then just set the list variable with the list
listvar.set(ls)

#or you can manipulate the data using Listbox()'s data manipulation
#   methods, such as .insert()
listbx1.insert(1, "Shiver me timbers!")
listbx2.insert(3, "Yo ho ho!")
listbx1.insert(5, "Ye scurvy dog!")
listbx2.insert('end', "Ye'll be walking the plank, Sharkbait!")

#you'll see this if you run this program from the command line
print(listbx1.get(5))

rootWin.mainloop()
```

You would do this a *little* bit differently if you had your tabs in their own classes, making the common variable global, for instance, but the same idea still applies: sharing a common `listvariable`.